# kB to MB using awk

Tags: bash

I have a script:

> ```
> bash -c "echo \$[\$(egrep '^Commit(Limit|ted_AS): ' /proc/meminfo | awk '{ print \$2 }' | tr '\n' '-')0]"
> ```

which returns result in `Kb` and I need to convert it to `Mb` by dividing it to 1024.

Comment: Please use the internationally agreed SI Units and abbreviations. **kB** denotes kilobytes and **MB** denotes megabytes https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte The `Mb` you use means megabits https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabit

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '/^Commit/{print $1,$2/1024,"Mb"}' /proc/meminfo
```

Output:

```
CommitLimit: 5536.77 Mb
Committed_AS: 13280.3 Mb
```